# Can not upgrade infinispan to 9.1.0.Final: ClassCastException

Tags: java, tomcat, logback, infinispan, infinispan-9

I am trying to upgrade infinispan from 8.2.4.Final to 9.1.0.Final, but get some errors from embedded slf4j while building tomcat war-file.

Logs:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/infinispan-embedded-9.1.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
> explanation.
>
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
> [org.jboss.slf4j.JBossLoggerFactory] 20-Jul-2017 16:07:34.170
>
> ERROR
> [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
> com.myapp.context.LogbackLoggingConfigurator.configureLoggingExternal
> Loading logger configuration from C:\my-files\conf\logback.xml
>
> **java.lang.ClassCastException**: org.jboss.slf4j.JBossLoggerFactory
> cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

The code, mentioned in logs:

```
public void configureLogging(final URL config) {
    final LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    try {
        lc.reset();

        final JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
        configurator.setContext(lc);
        configurator.doConfigure(config);
    } catch (final JoranException je) {
        logger.error("Unable to configure logback", je);
    }
    StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(lc);
}
```

And wrong line is here: `final LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();`

Firstly, I excluded slf4j-api from "infinispan-embedded" dependency, but unsuccessfully because slf4j is hardcoded.

Secondly, I added `<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/infinispan-embedded-9.1.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</packagingExcludes>` to maven-war-plugin (maybe with '!' symbol we cannot get access to nested jars, but I don't find another variants). Attempt was failed.

So, how can I fix this exception? Maybe it is possible to use maven-shade-plugin? But it seems unacceptable for my project.

Comment: I believe excluding classes won't work here. Infinispan Embedded, the uber jar as we call it, contains some logging classes inside the archive. The proper way to deal with it is to use so called small jars. Try out adding Infinispan Core to your deployment (and possibly other integration bits) instead of Infinispan Embedded.

Comment: Indeed, avoid uber jars, they're not designed for Maven/Gradle like envs.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem. I solve it with a trick. I exclude logback from dependencies. I used infinispan-embedded as logger. But I think it is not right way to solve the problem. I think "http://infinispan.org/" developers need to export codes about logger as another jar. Then we can exclude in maven. Actually It is not right way to be dependent logger jar because of another task.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem. I solve it with a trick. I exclude logback from dependencies. I used infinispan-embedded as logger. But I think it is not right way to solve the problem. I think "http://infinispan.org/" developers need to export codes about logger as another jar. Then we can exclude in maven. Actually It is not right way to be dependent logger jar because of another task.

I wrote to infinispan team and they quick respond. As they said infinispan-embedded is  "uber-jar" it is mean "all dependencies in one". You can use each dependencies of infinispan instead of it. infinispan-core and which you want to use.

You can see detail of the opened issue by clicking on this link  https://developer.jboss.org/message/975209?et=watches.email.thread#975209
on jboss website.